# Return IFormFileCollection from Rest API

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, iformfile

I have rest api application on asp core 2.1 where I have to return images. And on client application (asp mvc site) I need to get IFormFileCollection to work with it then. How can I do it? I can't understand either how to create IFormFile from existing file on rest api and return it or how to convert incoming FileResult to IFormFile

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. `IFormFile` is a construct for handling posted binary data from a `multipart-formdata`-encoded request. It is not something you would create yourself or return from an action.

If you want to return a file, you need to return a `FileResult` constructed from one of: a `string` path to a file on the filesystem, a `Stream` containing the data, or a `byte[]` containing the raw bytes of the file.

Additionally, it is not possible to return a "collection" of files from a single response. If you need to return multiple files, you'll need to put them in a container such as a zip archive and return that instead.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to return a multipart form response via `ASP NET Web Api` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static IFormFileCollection GetFormFileCollection()
    {
        var filesFolder = $" 
       {AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase}UploadFiles\\";
        List<string> filesPathsListToUpload = new List<string>();
        filesPathsListToUpload.Add($"{filesFolder}UploadFile1.png");
        filesPathsListToUpload.Add($"{filesFolder}UploadFile2.jpg");
        filesPathsListToUpload.Add($"{filesFolder}UploadFile3.bmp");

        FormFileCollection filesCollection = new FormFileCollection();
            foreach (var filePath in filesPathsListToUpload)
            {
                var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath);
                IFormFile file = new FormFile(stream, 0, stream.Length, "files", 
                Path.GetFileName(filePath))
                {
                    Headers = new HeaderDictionary(),
                    ContentType = filePath.Split('.')[1] == "jpg" ? "image/jpeg"
                        : filePath.Split('.')[1] == "png" ? "image/png"
                        : "image/bmp",
                };
    
                filesCollection.Add(file);
            }

            var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
            httpContext.Request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "multipart/form- 
            data");
            httpContext.Request.Form = new FormCollection(new Dictionary<string, 
            StringValues>(), filesCollection);

            return httpContext.Request.Form.Files;
    }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: The code reads files from disk, and returns an IFormFilCollection